# How to write SELECT query from 2 different tables based on result from 3rd table, while keeping order?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables where one table has 3 columns with foreign keys to the other two tables.
table album_posters_albums-

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| album_id|poster_id|albums_id|
+---------+---------+---------+
|     49  | 167     | NULL    |
|     49  | NULL    | 45      |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

album_id and albums_id references the album table and poster_id represents the poster table.
I need to

```
SELECT * FROM poster 
WHERE  poster_id IN (
                  SELECT poster_id 
                  FROM   album_poster_albums 
                  WHERE album_id=49);
```

IF the poster_id IS NULL:

```
SELECT * FROM album 
WHERE  album_id IN (
                  SELECT poster_id 
                  FROM album_poster_albums 
                  WHERE album_id=49).
```

The problem is I need to keep the posters and albums in the same order as they occur in the album_posters_albums table.

I was sending a query to get the list of ids, then looping through each result and querying the db to get either the poster or album but that is obviously very inefficient when I should be able to do it in one query.

Comment: Look up the `JOIN` part of the `SELECT` syntax.

Comment: Can you provide an example please? I don't see how any join will maintain the order of the linking table in the results.

Comment: What is the difference between `album_id` and `albums_id`?

Comment: Sounds like you need a unique id for the album_posters_albums table, which you can then order by. Otherwise, what does the "order" in that table mean?

Comment: An album can contain both posters and other albums, so the album_posters_albums table holds the reference to the album with album_id(49), albums_id(45) references the other album held by that album.

Comment: @beltouche interesting...

Comment: @beltouche Is it possible to run a different query for each row based on whether the subquery returns null? For example query poster table where poster_id is = to first result of subquery, if null query album table. Then repeat for each row. Or will it only query poster table first for all non null results, then query album table for all non null results?

Comment: Are you trying to get both the poster info (167) and the albums info (45) because at once, because they're both associated with album 49?

Comment: right. and trying to maintain the order they appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use INNER JOINS

```
SELECT album.*, poster.*
FROM album_poster_albums
INNER JOIN album ON album_poster_albums.albums_id = album.album_id
INNER JOIN poster ON album_poster_albums.poster_id = poster.poster_id
WHERE album_poster_albums.album_id = 49
```

Based on your comment about one row with a poster and one row with an album, UNION ALL might be what you're looking for. (We'd need to see more details about the tables and a few more rows to understand the ordering part.) This should give you an album row then a poster row for each album id.
Caveats: The number and the orders of columns in the album and poster tables must be the same. Also, the data types of those columns must be the same or compatible. (I haven't used a UNION, or UNION ALL, in a very long time.)

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT album.*
    FROM album_poster_albums
    INNER JOIN album ON album_poster_albums.albums_id = album.album_id
    WHERE album_poster_albums.album_id = 49
    UNION ALL
    SELECT poster.*
    FROM album_poster_albums
    INNER JOIN poster ON album_poster_albums.poster_id = poster.poster_id
    WHERE album_poster_albums.album_id = 49
)
ORDER BY album_id
```

Comment: Query returned empty set and returned album and poster tables in 1 row, all the album fields then all the poster fields in a single row.

Comment: And that sounds to me like what you wanted, because that one row is a single ordering with the relevant info. If that's incorrect, I just don't understand what you're going for. Sorry.

Comment: I need the album or the poster in 1 row, then the next album or poster in the following row. So poster with id of 167 would be first row, second row would be the album with id of 45.

Comment: Time to get to grips with table aliases, methinks

Comment: #DECLARE @rowId Int(11);

Comment: @beltouche, I was able to get your answer to show the correct 2 rows(after adding aliases and a few tweaks), but they're not in the correct order. After selecting an album with more records, it turns out all the albums return first, then all the posters, instead of original order. I think I may have to use case with if null.

Comment: @ Koteswara Rao, is there a benefit to using a variable instead of just appending a field and adding a value to it?

Comment: Yes, I would expect all the albums of an album, and then all the posters of that album, to appear. Again, you keep talking about maintaining an "original order", but there's nothing ordering the information in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

## DECLARE @rowId INT(11);

SET @rowId :=0;

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT @rowId:=@rowId+1,t.album_id,album.*
              FROM album_poster_albums t
              INNER JOIN album ON album.albums_id = t.albums_id
              WHERE t.album_id  = 49
              UNION
              SELECT @rowId:=@rowId + 2,t.album_id,poster.*
              FROM album_poster_albums s
              INNER JOIN poster ON poster.poster_id = t.poster_id
              WHERE t.album_id = 49) T
ORDER BY @rowId,t.album_id
```

Comment: I was able to get your answer to show the correct 2 rows(with a couple edits), but they're not in the correct order. After selecting an album with more records, it turns out all the albums return first, then all the posters, instead of original order. I think I may have to use case with if null.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create a new table with an auto increment field based on @beltouche comment. My Mysql is pretty rusty and I thought there may be a way using case or if null. I didn't need the unique id previously with how I wrote the queries.
In hindsight the solution is obvious.

```
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT albums.*, 1 AS type, t.id
                    FROM album_poster_album t
                    INNER JOIN albums ON albums.album_id = t.albums_id
                    WHERE t.album_id = 49
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT poster.*, 2 AS type, s.id
                    FROM album_poster_album s
                    INNER JOIN poster ON poster.posterID = s.poster_id
                    WHERE s.album_id = 49) T
    ORDER BY t.id
```